# PHP - Querying multiple tables from an array

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm really struggling trying to get these two queries (below) together with [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp). I'm passing an array through in _GET. I wanna select from two different mysql tables.

**URL array _GET example:**
www.mysite.com/users_slideshows[]=one&users_slideshows[]=two&users_slideshows[]=three

**Here are my two queries that i'm trying to combine:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','1234','root');
$records = array();

foreach ($_GET["users_slideshows"] as $djahjkdsh) {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM playlist_builder WHERE playlist_builder.volume IN ('".$djahjkdsh."') ");
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
    }
    $json = json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}

foreach ($_GET["users_slideshows"] as $djahjkdsh) {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM custom_slideshow WHERE custom_slideshow.volume IN ('".$djahjkdsh."') ");
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
    }
    $json = json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}
```

If I just choose from one table, it works perfect but it's only when I combine both together.

I've tried the following below... not happening

```sql
SELECT * FROM playlist_builder INNER JOIN custom_slideshow ON custom_slideshow.volume = playlist_builder.volume IN ('".$djahjkdsh."')
```

If anyone could help me on what I'm doing wrong, I would extremely appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You have implemented a [SQL injection security vulnerablity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).   You are taking input from the user and inserting it into a SQL query without any validation or escaping.     A user could craft input to transform their database query into any db operation they choose.    You need to learn to use prepared statements before doing any more coding involving web and databases.

Comment: I understand this. Thanks. I'll be working on improving this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect since you run two expressions in same logical `ON` clause. Simply separate the `ON` clauses into multiple expressions. Also, with one value, use equality over `IN`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM playlist_builder 
INNER JOIN custom_slideshow ON custom_slideshow.volume = playlist_builder.volume 
AND playlist_builder.volume = ?)
```

Alternatively, with a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM playlist_builder 
INNER JOIN custom_slideshow ON custom_slideshow.volume = playlist_builder.volume 
WHERE playlist_builder.volume = ?)
```

**PHP** *(using [parameterization](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and table aliases)*

```php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM playlist_builder p 
        INNER JOIN custom_slideshow c ON c.volume = p.volume AND p.volume = ?';

foreach ($_GET["users_slideshows"] as $djahjkdsh) {

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $djahjkdsh);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row =  $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
    }
    $json = json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);    

    $stmt->close();
}
```